# How to select a element using querySelector that has dynamic name?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lwc-dom, lightning-buttonicon

I have a lightning-button-icon with dynamic name and i want to update its selected attribute based on the name. Can someone tell me how can i do that?

my code (**UPDATED**):

```
<lightning-layout-item size="3">
                    <lightning-button-icon-stateful
                        data-class="slelectState"
                        data-index1={inx1}
                        data-index2={inx2}
                        data-id={pair.key}
                        name={pair.key}
                        icon-name="utility:check"
                        selected={selectState}
                        alternative-text="True"
                        onclick={handleSelect}>
                    </lightning-button-icon-stateful>
                    <lightning-button-icon-stateful
                        data-class="UnslelectState"
                        data-index1={inx1}
                        data-index2={inx2}
                        data-id={pair.key}
                        name={pair.key}
                        icon-name="utility:close"
                        selected={unSelectState}
                        alternative-text="False"
                        onclick={handleUnSelect}>
                    </lightning-button-icon-stateful>
                </lightning-layout-item>
```

I tried this code `this.template.querySelector(`[name="${selectedname}"]`)` as per @sfdcfox answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256007/how-do-you-define-an-element-with-an-id-attribute-using-lwc) but it gave me null value.

Comment: can you share the code how you declared selectedname variable ?

Comment: Also please share the handleSelect method

Comment: You cant use name attribute, you have to use data-* attribute only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, You can only query elements with the attributes that are exposed on the element - in this case `lightning-button-icon-stateful`. The attribute `name` is not directly placed on this element but it is on internal element.

If you want to see what items you can query, look at the following example.

For example

```
<lightning-button-icon-stateful
                                    data-index1={inx1}
                                    data-index2={inx2}
                                    name={pairkey}
                                    icon-name="utility:check"
                                    selected={selectState}
                                    alternative-text="True"
                                    onclick={handleSelect}>
    </lightning-button-icon-stateful>
```

When you do `console.log(this.template.querySelector('lightning-button-icon-stateful'));`

Output in console:

```
<lightning-button-icon-stateful c-app_app="" data-index1="12" data-index2="13"></lightning-button-icon-stateful>
```

So we can only do querySelector with attributes data-* (data-index1, data-index2) and c-app_app (auto generated based on class).

It cannot retrieve elements with other attributes using querySelector, so the following will always be null.

```
console.log(this.template.querySelector('lightning-button-icon-stateful[name="12"]'));
```

So in short, you can only retrieve **data** attributes in the given example as other elements are actually placed on internal element.

Reference:
[How to target LWC by name attribute?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264202/how-to-target-lwc-by-name-attribute)

Alternatively, you can query based on DOM element and iterate the result and verify the name. something like this.

```
this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-button-icon-stateful').forEach(ele => {
            if(ele.name == selectedname){
                //TODO
            }
        });
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you. Now one another issue is that i have two "lightning-button-icon-stateful" buttons with same . Is there a way to query multiple data- attributes? Please see updated question for html markup changes.

Comment: nevermind.. i figured it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

For LWC html

> 

```
                <template for:each={questions} for:item="q">
                    <p key={q.Id}>{q.Sequence_Number__c}.{q.Question_Text__c} <br>
                    <lightning-textarea data-id={q.Sequence_Number__c} name={q.Sequence_Number__c} required value="" placeholder="Type your answer here..." label='max length 200 characters' maxlength="200" min-length="10" message-when-too-long="A maximum of 200 characters are allowed in a tweet." message-when-value-missing="You need to fill all answers" field-level-help="Please fill the answers to submit" ></lightning-textarea>
                    <br><br>
                    </p>
                </template>
            </template>
```

In LWC Js COntroller use this code.

> for(var i=1; i<=this.questions.length; i++){
> console.log('Answer no : '+i);

```
    this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-textarea').forEach(ele => {
        if(ele.name == i){
            console.log(ele.value);
        }
    });
    
}
```

Where this.questions is a list from apex controller.