# How can I get the nearest data-id of the clicked element?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, onclick

On an **html** page, I want to dynamically draw elements and I want to determine the `data-id` the nearest element `li` that contains the clicked element `a`, and then add a class to the element with the `li` with `data-id` so that the element is highlighted as active:

```
<form onclick={handleClickVerticalNavigation}>
<nav class="slds-nav-vertical" aria-label="Sub page">
    <div class="slds-nav-vertical__section">
        <h2 id="entity-header" class="slds-nav-vertical__title">Months</h2>
        <div for:each={listMonth} for:item="month" key={month.Id}>
            <ul aria-describedby="entity-header">
            <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item" id={month.Id} data-id={month.Id}>
                <a href="#" class="slds-nav-vertical__action" aria-current="false">{month.nameMonth}
                <span class="slds-badge slds-col_bump-left">
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">:</span>{month.countAmount}
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">New Items</span>
                </span>
                <span class="slds-badge slds-col_bump-left">
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">:</span>{month.countIncome}
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">New Items</span>
                </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</form>
```

[image]

the transmitted `listMonth` looks like this:

```
[{"Id":"0-January","nameMonth":"January","countAmount":0,"countIncome":0},{"Id":"1-February","nameMonth":"February","countAmount":0,"countIncome":0},{"Id":"2-March","nameMonth":"March","countAmount":0,"countIncome":0},{"Id":"3-April","nameMonth":"April","countAmount":0,"countIncome":0},{"Id":"4-May","nameMonth":"May","countAmount":0,"countIncome":0}]
```

I have experimented a lot with the handler method, and this is how it looks now:

```
handleClickVerticalNavigation(event){
    let returnTarget = event.target;
    if (returnTarget.tagName != 'li'){
        let returnId = event.target.id;
        this.template.querySelector(returnId).className='slds-is-active';
    } else {
        console.log('click not on li');
    }
}
```

I get into the **if** block and nothing else happens, because I don't get the `id` and the **class** can't be set either...

I have seen [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256007/how-do-you-define-an-element-with-an-id-attribute-using-lwc) question and some others, but have not solved my problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your click event will capture the `A` anchor tag, so you will have to navigate back to `li` tag and then get the `id`.

like this : `e.target.closest('li').id`

Your click event navigate to closest parent `li` tag and get the `id`, as the html has `id` on `li` tag.

```
<li class="slds-nav-vertical__item" id={month.Id} data-id={month.Id}>
```

**UPDATE**

You can use queryselector like this:

```
let returnId = event.target.closest('li').getAttribute('data-id');
this.template.querySelector('li[data-id="'+returnId+'"]').classList.add('slds-is-active')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I get the `id`, only for some reason it is slightly changed... For example, instead of `0-January`, I get `0-January-45`. `-45` is always added to each id.

Comment: @Nagedra I decided to get the `date-id` and now I get the correct value.: `let returnDateId = event.target.closest('li').getAttribute('date-id');`. But there is a problem with installing the class. That's how I'm trying to install it: `this.template.querySelector('li[date-id="${returnDateId}"]').className='slds-is-active';`. And I can't do it...

Comment: @uniqueuser Updated the code.

Comment: @unique user, id's are changed on runtime, you should never set or use id's to access the DOM using querySelectors, us a custom attribute instead

Comment: @Nagedra Singh, thank you so much for your help! This solved my problem.